# How to stop foreach looping for sub courses?

Tags: php, html

When I click Linuxbasics if default page is there it should open . I am getting the default page but my li is looping .Here from my code I used multidimensional array. Below is my  code and image.I shown in Image I am getting linux basics twice:
[image]

```
<ul class="sub-menu" style="border-right: 2px solid #012340;">
<?php foreach($outContentArrResults AS $keyCmsId => $valArrMenu){?>
    <?php if($valArrMenu['cPId']==0){?>
        <li class="menu-item-has-children">
            <a href="#"><?php echo isset($valArrMenu['cName']) ? $valArrMenu['cName']:'';?></a>
            <?php $slugName = isset($valArrMenu['cSName']) ? $valArrMenu['cSName']:'';
            $id =isset($valArrMenu['cId']) ? $valArrMenu['cId']:'';
            $courseChild =isset($valArrMenu['courseChild']) ? $valArrMenu['courseChild']:'';?>
        <?php foreach($courseChild AS $keyId => $courseResult){
        if($courseResult['cPId']==$id){?>
            <ul class="sub-menu" style="border-right: 2px solid #012340;border-left: 2px solid #012340;">
                <?php foreach($courseChild AS $keyId => $courseResult){?>
                <?php if($courseResult['cPId']==$id){?>
                <?php $courseSubChild =isset($courseResult['courseChild']) ? $courseResult['courseChild']:'';
                    foreach($courseSubChild AS $keyIdsss => $courseSubResult){
                    $Subid =isset($courseSubResult['cId']) ? $courseSubResult['cId']:'';
                    $SubslugName =isset($courseSubResult['cSName']) ? $courseSubResult['cSName']:'';?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $config['LIVE_URL'];?>courses/<?php echo isset($slugName) ? $slugName :'';?>/<?php echo isset($courseResult['cSName']) ? $courseResult['cSName']:'';?>/<?php echo $SubslugName;?>/<?php echo isset($courseSubResult['conSName']) ? $courseSubResult['conSName']:'';?>"><?php echo isset($courseResult['cName']) ? $courseResult['cName']:'';?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php }?>
                <?php }?>
                <?php }?>
            </ul>
        <?php }?>
        <?php }?>
        </li>
    <?php }?>
<?php }?>
```

Here is my array:

```
  Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [cId] => 1
        [cName] => Linux
        [cSName] => linux
        [isTryItEditor] => 0
        [cImg] => 
        [cCDate] => 2016-08-10 11:47:53
        [cPId] => 0
        [conSName] => 
        [conIDPage] => 
        [courseChild] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [cId] => 2
                        [cName] => Linux Basics
                        [cSName] => linux-basics
                        [isTryItEditor] => 0
                        [cImg] => 
                        [cCDate] => 2016-08-10 11:48:51
                        [cPId] => 1
                        [conSName] => 
                        [conIDPage] => 
                        [courseChild] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [cId] => 4
                                        [cName] => basic commands
                                        [cSName] => basic-commands
                                        [isTryItEditor] => 0
                                        [cImg] => 
                                        [cCDate] => 2016-08-10 11:56:41
                                        [cPId] => 2
                                        [conSName] => hii
                                        [conIDPage] => 1
                                        [courseChild] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [cId] => 3
                                        [cName] => Filter commands
                                        [cSName] => filter-commands
                                        [isTryItEditor] => 0
                                        [cImg] => 
                                        [cCDate] => 2016-08-10 11:49:14
                                        [cPId] => 2
                                        [conSName] => 
                                        [conIDPage] => 
                                        [courseChild] => Array
                                            (
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
        )
     )
```

Comment: Where you want to stop the loop just use break statement.

Comment: your code is hell. however, If I spotted it correctly, your innermost loop prints the wrong stuff.

Comment: Why did you put the C flag ? I don't see any C code here.

Comment: Consider separating your PHP logic from your HTML display. In PHP build your arrays in the exact shape you need first. Then later, in HTML you can just `echo` the result or loop through the correctly formatted array.  It will make your code much easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your value in the array  casue from what it looks like you intial
foreach loop is causing the problem

and then use  if(!in_array())  to only print values that are not there

Answer (score 0):

As "BeetleJuice" mentioned, try to first test logic with pure PHP code, and then integrate with HTML, it would ease up the work.

Regarding your code, it seems your innermost loop has wrong data print. Just do below change in your code to identify the issue: Instead of

```
<li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $config['LIVE_URL'];?>courses/<?php echo isset($slugName) ? $slugName :'';?>/<?php echo isset($courseResult['cSName']) ? $courseResult['cSName']:'';?>/<?php echo $SubslugName;?>/<?php echo isset($courseSubResult['conSName']) ? $courseSubResult['conSName']:'';?>"><?php echo isset($courseResult['cName']) ? $courseResult['cName']:'';?></a>
                </li>

                run this,

                <li>
                    <?php echo $courseResult['cId']?>
                </li>
```

As you have unique cid for each level of record, you can easily trackdown the issue.

Hope this helps.

Thanks